# Xcode - Change the image of a button every iteration of for-loop

Tags: xcode, memory, for-loop

I'm creating a memory game and want to change the images of four buttons each iteration in a for-loop. What actually happens is that nothing happens until the last iteration of the loop.

When the button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)bNewRound:(id)sender {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    numbers1[i] = arc4random()%4+1;
    NSLog(@"%i: %i", i, numbers1[i]);

    if (numbers1[i] == 1) {
        [self b1On];
    }
    if (numbers1[i] == 2) {
        [self b2On];
    }
    if (numbers1[i] == 3) {
        [self b3On];
    }
    if (numbers1[i] == 4) {
        [self b4On];
    }
    sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The method for changing the images of the buttons:

```
- (void)b1On {
NSLog(@"b1 state1");
[self.button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"memory_green.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

bool1 = FALSE;
[self b2Off];
[self b3Off];
[self b4Off];
}
- (void)b1Off {
//  NSLog(@"b1 state2");
[self.button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"memory_grey.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

bool1 = TRUE;
}
```

(only for button 1 but you get it)

I follow the code in the log and everything works fine, every second a new number is generated and saved in the array, the b1On-method (or b2On, b3On etc) runs but the line

```
[self.button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"memory_green.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

wont change the image each iteration. 
But when the for-loop is over the last (random) button in the array will change color to green.

Why aren´t the images updated for every iteration of the for-loop?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use delay in iteration. So that compiler is so fast which is you expect will take time to effect..

Answer (score 0):

1. Never ever use `sleep()` on the main thread
2. UI updates don't happen immediately. They happen at the end of the current run loop, that means after your method is done.

You could use a NSTimer. Something like this should work:

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    _timerCount--;
    if (_timerCount <= 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    // do something
}

- (void)startTimer {
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timerCount = 10;
    _timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```